# To allow Backspace in validating date format

Tags: javascript

In the below Javascript code I am validating the dateformat in which backspace and delete key is not working.

```
function AcceptDateCharacters(event, separator) {

    var keyCode = event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if((separator.length != 1) && (keyCode > 8 && keyCode < 45))  
    {
        return false;
    }
    //lets allow digits
    var expression = "^[0-9";

    //lets allow the separator character
    expression += separator;

    //lets complete the expression
    expression += "]$";

    var regex = new RegExp(expression);
    return AcceptRegExOnly(event, regex)
   // var keyCode = event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode;
   //if ((keyCode >8 && keyCode <= 45))
    return true; 
};
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "backspace and delete is not working"

Comment: @edi9999 keys Del,Backspace

Comment: Where's the code for AcceptRegExOnly(..)?

Comment: Use <input type="date"> instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just add an if statement for backspace and delete?

```
  function AcceptDateCharacters(event, separator) {

        var keyCode = event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode;
        if((separator.length != 1) && (keyCode > 8 && keyCode < 45))  
        {
            return false;
        }
// added conditional
        if(keyCode == 8 || keyCode == 46){
            return true;
        }
        //lets allow digits
        var expression = "^[0-9";

        //lets allow the separator character
        expression += separator;

        //lets complete the expression
        expression += "]$";

        var regex = new RegExp(expression);
        return AcceptRegExOnly(event, regex)
       // var keyCode = event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode;
       //if ((keyCode >8 && keyCode <= 45))
        return true; 
    };
```

Comment: You need to debug the code and see what's going on.  All my addition will do is return true if it's a backspace or a delete.  There is something else going on that's preventing the default behavior.

Comment: If you can, I would recommend creating a jsfiddle to test out the basic code.